# Isomorphism of modules + tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals, tensor-products

Is it true that:
$$M{\otimes}_{A}(A/I) \cong M/IM$$
and
$$IM \cong I {\otimes}_AM$$
where $A$ is a commutative ring, $M$ an $A$-module, and $I \subset A$ an ideal.

Comment: Yes.  One reference for this result is Atiyah & MacDonald's commutative algebra textbook (although I believe the first result is an exercise).

Comment: There is, however, a natural map $I \otimes_A M \to IM$ which is surjective. This might help you prove the first equation.

Comment: The map Dylan mentions is also injective precisely when $Tor(R/I,M)=0$. So of course this is the only time you get an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a proof of your first equation given in page 17 of Osborne's *Basic Homological Algebra* book (presuming you have defined tensor product in terms of the usual universal property). I'll give an outline here

Define $\phi':M \times A/I \to M/IM$ by $\phi'(m,a+I) = am + IM.$ Check that this is well defined. Suppose there is a bilinear $\psi:  M \times A/I \to G$. Using the fact that $A \otimes M \simeq M$ we have the following diagram

[image lost]

$\theta$ and $\phi$ come from the above tensor product ($A \otimes M \simeq M$). Convince yourself that $\theta'$ is induced from $\theta$, that the diagram commutes and that $\theta'$ is unique.

Comment: ImageShack seems to have deleted your image [and replaced it with an ad banner.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771) If you can, please reupload the image (or something equivalent) using the image upload button in the editor toolbar (which will upload it to Stack Exchange's imgur account).

Answer (score 5):

The 1st claim ok. The 2nd not: $A=\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$, $I=2A$, $M=A/2A$. In that case $IM=0$, but because $I$ is isomorphic to $A/2A$ as an $A$-module, we have $I\otimes_AM$ isomorphic to $M$ as well. Basically you are tensoring the short exact sequence
$$
0\rightarrow I\rightarrow A\rightarrow A/I\rightarrow 0
$$
with $M$. The resulting sequence will be exact except possibly at the first spot. Look up *flat* module for more information. The proof of the first result is also there, because we can identify the image of $I\otimes M\rightarrow A\otimes M\cong M$ with $IM$ (as pointed out by Dylan).

Comment: More generally, $M/A\otimes N/B \cong M\!\otimes\!N/(M\!\otimes\!B\!+\!A\!\otimes\!N)$, right? If $M\!=\!R^m$ and $N\!=\!R^n$, then $M/A=Coker A'$ and $N/B=Coker B'$ where $A',B'$ are matrices with columns the generators of $A,B$ respectively. There holds $Coker A'\otimes Coker B'\cong Coker(I_m\!\otimes\!B'\!+\!A'\!\otimes\!I_n)$, where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of matrices, correct?